# Modificar una columna de una tabla segun una operacion matematica

Tags: java, mysql

Hola estoy haciendo un programa de gestion de una jugueteria en Java con MySql local con Xampp. Le agregue varias opciones y ahora quiero que se pueda modificar los precios de la tabla juguetes en funcion de un porcentage que el cliente quiera aumentar. Estoy usando netbeans IDE 8.0.1.
Mi idea es crear una ventana que pueda seleccionar que tipo de juguetes aumentar (madera, plastico, etc) y poder poner el porcentage de aumento.
La parte que no veo como encarar es la de la modificacion de la columna precio en la tabla de la base de datos

Gracias desde ya.

Este es el codigo que uso para llenar una jtable con los datos de la tabla juguetes y poder editar cada juguete por separado.
Lo que quiero hacer es poder modificar los precios de los juguetes segun el Tipo de juguete (Madera, Plastico, Goma Espuma).

```java
try {
            Connection cn = Conexion.conectar();
            PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(
                    "select id_juguetes, nombre, Precio, Tipo, Costo, proveedor.nombre_prov, "
                            + "Stock from juguetes, proveedor WHERE juguetes.Proveedor = proveedor.id_proveedor");

            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

            jTable_juguetes = new JTable(model);
            jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable_juguetes);

            model.addColumn(" ");
            model.addColumn("Nombre");
            model.addColumn("Precio");
            model.addColumn("Tipo");
            model.addColumn("Costo");
            model.addColumn("Proveedor");
            model.addColumn("Stock");

            while (rs.next()) {
                Object[] fila = new Object[7];

                for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                    fila[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
                }
                model.addRow(fila);
            }
            cn.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Error al llenar tabla." + e);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al mostrar información, ¡Contacte al administrador!");
        }

        jTable_juguetes.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                int fila_point = jTable_juguetes.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                int columna_point = 1;

                if(fila_point > -1){
                    juguete_update = (String)model.getValueAt(fila_point, columna_point);
                    InformacionJuguetes informacion_juguete = new InformacionJuguetes();
                    informacion_juguete.setVisible(true);
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Podrías agregar código de lo que haz intentado hasta el momento.

Comment: GFlores98, hay en la pregunta agregue el codigo que tengo hasta ahora.

Comment: Ya encontre la solucion, no se como marcar la pregunta como cerrada o si podria indicar como lo solucione, por si alguien mas le podria servir.

Comment: Responde tu pregunta. Agregas toda la info de la solucion y luego a tu respuesta la marcas como "Aceptada".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya logre solucionar el tema de la modificacion de la columna precios solamente para un tipo de juguetes.
Copio el codigo de la solucion:

```
int tipo;
    float porcentaje, multip;
    String sql = "";
    tipo = cmb_tipo.getSelectedIndex();
    porcentaje = Float.parseFloat(jTextField_Porcentaje.getText());
    multip = (porcentaje / 100) + 1;


    if (tipo == 1) {
        sql = "UPDATE juguetes SET Precio = Precio * '" + multip + "' WHERE  'Goma Espuma' = Tipo";
    } else if (tipo == 2) {
        sql = "UPDATE juguetes SET Precio = Precio * '" + multip + "' WHERE  'Madera' = Tipo";
    } else if (tipo == 3) {
        sql = "UPDATE juguetes SET Precio = Precio * '" + multip + "' WHERE  'Plastico' = Tipo";
    } else if (tipo == 4) {
        sql = "UPDATE juguetes SET Costo = Costo * '" + multip + "' ";
    }
    try {
        Connection cn1 = Conexion.conectar();
        PreparedStatement pst = cn1.prepareStatement(sql);

        pst.executeUpdate();
        cn1.close();
        jTable_precio.setVisible(false);
        jTable_precio.setVisible(true);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Actualizacion correcta.");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error en la actualizacion " + e);
    }
```

Espero el metodo le sirva a alguien mas.